# Implement takeWhile with fold

Tags: haskell

How can I implement the takeWhile function in Haskell using fold?

```
takeWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

I tried a strategy similiar to implementing filter like this

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter f = foldr (\x acc -> if f x then x : acc else acc) []
```

But how can I stop when f x is false?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just change `acc` to `[]` in the `else` branch:

```
takeWhile f = foldr (\x acc -> if f x then x : acc else []) []
```

The idea is that you’re lazily building the result list as you consume elements from the input list, so you return `[]` when you want to terminate the result list.

```
takeWhile (< 3) [0..]
=
0 : takeWhile (< 3) [1..]
=
0 : 1 : takeWhile (< 3) [2..]
=
0 : 1 : 2 : takeWhile (< 3) [3..]
=
0 : 1 : 2 : []
=
[0, 1, 2]
```

This also illustrates how Haskell lists are really *streams* of values. Right folds are little state machines that move step-by-step through an input stream to generate an output stream.